# Как ограничить количество выводимых позиций в "производителях" Opencart?

Tags: php, javascript, opencart

Мне нужно выводить на странице производителей только первые 3 позиции. Как их можно ограничить? Сейчас они выводятся все в алфавитном порядке (по стандарту). Буду благодарен за помощь.

Мне нужно на главной странице товара выводить любые 3 производителя. Я решил это сделать с помощью модуля, который сделал сам. 
Принцип работы модуля простой - он полностью копирует функционал страницы manufacturer_list, следовательно, он у меня на главной странице выводит всех производителей. Пример того, что сейчас получается здесь http://www.mactedesign.com/ (как видно, они идут в ряд и их очень много, а мне нужно всего 3).

Код контроллера модуля manufacturers.php :

```html
<?php class ControllerModuleManufacturers extends Controller { public function index() { $this->load->language('product/manufacturer'); $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title'); $data['text_brands'] = $this->language->get('text_brands'); $data['text_index'] = $this->language->get('text_index'); $data['brands'] = array(); $this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');
$results = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturersByOrder(); //echo "<pre>"; print_r($setting);
  $this->load->model('tool/image');
  
  foreach ($results as $result) {
    
    if (is_numeric(utf8_substr($result['name'], 0, 1))) {
     $key = '0 - 9';
    } else {
     $key = utf8_substr(utf8_strtoupper($result['name']), 0, 1);
    }
    
    if (!isset($data['brands'][$key])) {
     $data['brands'][$key]['name'] = $key;
    }
 
   $data['brands'][$key]['manufacturer'][] = array(
    'name'  => $result['name'],
    'image'  => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_height')),
    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id']),
                'limit'              => 3
   );
  }
  
  if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/manufacturers.tpl')) {
   return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/manufacturers.tpl', $data);
  } else {
   return $this->load->view('default/template/module/manufacturers.tpl', $data);
  }
 }
 
}
```

Код шаблона вывода модуля:

```html
<h3>Top Catalogue</h3>
<div id="manu" class="owl-carouse">
  <?php if ($brands) { ?>
  <?php foreach ($brands as $brand) { ?>

  <?php if ($brand[ 'manufacturer']) { ?>

  <?php foreach ($brand[ 'manufacturer'] as $manufacturer) { ?>
  <div class="item text-center">

    <a href="<?php echo $manufacturer['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $manufacturer['image']; ?>" class="img-responsive"></a>
    <?php echo $manufacturer[ 'name']; ?>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте пример кода, который показывает 1) Данные 2) что с ними делаете вы. Ну и если хотите скриншоты или пример вывода как вам надо. Без явного примера кода мало кто решится вам помочь т.к. ваш вопрос не содержит "якорей"

Comment: Сейчас добавлю код в пост

Comment: Отредактировал пост.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой, "топорный" вариант:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($results as $result) {

                if (is_numeric(utf8_substr($result['name'], 0, 1))) {
                    $key = '0 - 9';
                } else {
                    $key = utf8_substr(utf8_strtoupper($result['name']), 0, 1);
                }

                if (!isset($data['brands'][$key])) {
                    $data['brands'][$key]['name'] = $key;
                }

            $data['brands'][$key]['manufacturer'][] = array(
                'name'  => $result['name'],
                'image'  => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_height')),
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id']),
                'limit'              => 3
            );
$count++;
            if ($count >= 3) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек. Пускай метод и радикальный, но рабочий.